# UI issue using Grand Central Dispatch and UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios6, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to create my own view that is similar to `UIAlertView`. I have pretty much done this by adding a few subviews to my custom view and then adding my custom view as a subview to `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window]`. I have also implemented my own delegation to remove the view from the window once a button in the alert view has been pressed.

When the delegate view controller loads, it runs a method in the background, and once it is finished, I am running an `updateUI` method on the main queue. It is in this `updateUI` method that the alert view is shown. I do this using GCD:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self updateUI]; });
```

The problem that I am running into is that my delegate is a view controller embedded in a navigation controller, and when I press "back" to pop this delegate view controller off before the background method finishes, the alert view will be shown on the parent view controller. Pressing the button in the alert view does not do anything, as the delegate is now off the navigation controller stack.

Does anyone know why this alert view is still shown, and how I could prevent this from happening? I would think that popping the delegate view controller off would prevent its `updateUI` method from being called, but it looks like it is anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your view controller is removed from the navigation stack it is most probably still being retained by your block that runs in the background. Therefore, although not on screen, it will still receive your messages.

If I have understood you correctly, you are adding a subview to your application window. That explains why your custom alert view is still being presented even when your view controller is off the screen.

Not necessarily the best, but one method to avoid the alert view from being presented, is to check for your view controller's view's superview. If the superview is *nil*, your view controller is not visible and you can effectively avoid displaying the alert.

Comment: Thanks for answering. After reading your response, I experimented with making weak references to variables in my blocks, but I haven't figured out how to make that approach work yet. But checking the view's superview works great. Thanks again.